# VueJS can multiple elements call the same method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a form with dynamic elements, so sometimes it might be 5 file upload elements and sometimes only 1.

But I was wondering if its OK to let multiple elements use the same method on vue?

Eg:

```
<input type="file" @change="processImage(row.id)" name="img_1"class="img_upload_1">
<input type="file" @change="processImage(row.id)" name="img_2"class="img_upload_2">
<input type="file" @change="processImage(row.id)" name="img_3"class="img_upload_3">
```

Then in my vueJS file the method looks like this:

```
processImage(index) {
      var rowIndex = this.rows.map(item => item.id).indexOf(index);
      this.rows[rowIndex].img = $('.img_upload_' + index)[0].files[0];
    },
```

Everything works fine, I just wanted to ask in case there is some different way that is considered best practise.

Thanks

Comment: Sure, I can't see why not, actually it is better so you don't have to repeat yourself

Comment: It's fine. If you also pass `$event` to the method, you can use `event.target.files[0]` instead of having to query for the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's OK to call the same method from multiple elements.** In my experience it happens inside `v-for` loop mostly.

I don't have enough info about your case, but you can consider using HTML5 `input`, which allows you to upload multiple files:

```html
<input type="file" name="img" multiple>
```